# Fixed block with negative z-index overlaps the body background

Tags: html, css, fixed

I have a block with fixed positioning and negative z-index I want to be behind the body:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}
.sidebar {
    z-index: -999;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    min-height: 100%; width: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3kcqfbuv/

However, for the reason unknown to me, it positions behind the body content, BUT keeps overlapping the body background defined explicitly. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Could you explain clearly, what you need to behind the body?

Comment: @stanze .sidebar is a sidebar that is positioned behind the body. After a button is clicked I want the body to slide left (e.g. width margin-left: -200px) thus revealing the sidebar.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. because you can't put anything behind body.

Comment: You don't use z-index to hide stuff which you want to reveal on any given event. Use `display` property, absolute positioning outside visible area, or `opacity` for this.

Comment: @connexo an upper layer is smoothly sliding left revealing an underlying layer behind it. I don't see any way to do that with opacity or display property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Body is not an actual layer that can overlap any other layer...

One solution that solves what you want, is to create another div layer as your desktop/body.

```
<style>
html, body, .desktop {
    min-height: 100%;
}
.desktop {
    background: green;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;
    width: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
    z-index: -999;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    min-height: 100%; width: 200px;
    background: red;
}
</style>

<div class="desktop">
  <div class="content">
    Pellentesque mollis diam at egestas lacinia. In a pharetra risus. Aenean in libero. 
    Nam sollicitudin at erat quis maximus. Nam aliquet ornare nibh, sit amet.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid an extra wrapper, but this seems to be the only solution. Bummer!

Answer (score 0):

```
body {

    position: absolute;
    background: green;
}
.sidebar {

    position: relative;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    min-height: 100%; width: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

i have change here position on body to absolute and position of sidebar to relative. and removed z-index -999 from sidebar... its working for me

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3kcqfbuv/3/) is fiddle link

Comment: Thanks! This one works, however I need body to be positioned relatively.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the only solution is the extra wrapper like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ysh1s58/)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">
        Pellentesque mollis diam at egestas lacinia. In a pharetra risus. Aenean in libero. 
        Nam sollicitudin at erat quis maximus. Nam aliquet ornare nibh, sit amet.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar"></div>

html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background: green;
}

.sidebar {
    z-index: -999;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```